# Autocomplete search form, search in the middle of texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using the autocomplete to search the query.

In this source code, if you input `ac` you can get `accepts`, `action_name`.

However, I would like to get `action_name` with input `name` as a normal search form.

How can I make it?

```
$(function() {
  var data = [
    'accepts',
    'action_name',
    'add',
    'add_column',
    'add_index',
    'add_timestamps',
    'after_create',

  ];

  $('#txtKeywd').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      response(
        $.grep(data, function(value){
          return value.indexOf(request.term) === 0;
        })
      );
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    'accepts',
    'action_name',
    'add',
    'add_column',
    'add_index',
    'add_timestamps',
    'after_create',
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Comment: THanks it works well form and very simple. I might have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the autocomplete plugin this will do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var data = [
    'accepts',
    'action_name',
    'add',
    'add_column',
    'add_index',
    'add_timestamps',
    'after_create',

  ];

  $('#txtKeywd').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp( re, "i" );
        var a = $.grep( data, function(item,index){
            return matcher.test(item);
        });
        response( a );
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 2
  });    

});
```

You need to override the default regex used for autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

1 . Instead of just checking if the value is in the data element you can split the data element by `-` and `_`.

```
value.split(/-|_/)
```

2 . Then loop through it with a `forEach()` which takes as a parameter a function. `e` is the data element's value.

```
value.split(/-|_/).forEach(function(e) {});
```

3 . Then we just check if the input is in the `e` string

```
if(e.indexOf(request.term) === 0) {}
```

4 . If true **and only if true** we need to tell the `grep()` we're in that we have a successful match. To do so we need to set a boolean.

```
if(e.indexOf(request.term) === 0) { isIn = true; return; }
```

Above `return;` will end the search in the current split data element.

Here is the full code:

```js
$(function() {
  var data = [
    'accepts',
    'action_name',
    'add',
    'add_column',
    'add_index',
    'add_timestamps',
    'after_create',
  ];

  $('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      response(
        $.grep(data, function(value) {
          let isIn;
          value.split(/-|_/).forEach(function(e) {
            if(e.indexOf(request.term) === 0) { isIn = true; return; }
          });
          return isIn
        })  
      );
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    delay: 500,
    minLength: 2
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Of course, this can be improved by splitting all the data values once on page load and store them in a special array to check.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```js
var data = [
  'accepts',
  'action_name',
  'add',
  'add_column',
  'add_index',
  'add_timestamps',
  'after_create',
];

function split(val) {
    return val.split(/ \s*/);
}
function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

$("#opt")
  .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
          var term = request.term,
              results = [];
          term = extractLast(request.term);
          if (term.length > 0) {
              results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(data, term);
          }
          response(results);
      },
      focus: function() {
          return false; // prevent value inserted on focus
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {

      }
  });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="opt">Type Here:</label><br/>
  <input id="opt" size="50">
</div>
```